# Render multimensional array in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have array like this in my controller :

```
foreach ($entities as $temp) {
    $semesters[]['romanic'] = $data1;
    $semesters[]['grouping'] = data2;
}
```

I can render it if my array like this `$semesters['romanic'][]`. But for some reason I can't make it like that. I've try several times like this :

```
{% for semester in semesters %}
{{ semester['romanic'] }} 
{{ semester['grouping'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for key, semester in semesters %}
{{ semesters[key]['romanic'] }} 
{{ semesters[key]['grouping'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

I can render this if using 2 loops :

```
{% for semester in semesters %}
{% for temp in semester %}
{{ temp }} 
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But I need to do this with just 1 loop. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should probably change is creating your array in PHP to:

```
foreach ($entities as $temp) {
    $c = count($semesters);
    $semesters[$c]['romanic'] = $data1;
    $semesters[$c]['grouping'] = $data2;
}
```

And in your Twig you can simple use:

```
{% for item in semesters %}
  {{ item.romanic }} {{ item.grouping }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Here's the sample PHP code to test it:

```
$semesters = array();

$semesters[0]['romanic'] = 1;
$semesters[0]['grouping'] = 2;
$semesters[1]['romanic'] = 3;
$semesters[1]['grouping'] = 4;
$twig->addGlobal ('semesters', $semesters);
echo $twig->render('index.html.twig');
```

The result is:

```
1 2 
3 4
```

as expected

Comment: Thank you for nice example for this. I made an alternative before your answer (edited in my question). But I like your coding, simple and readable.